# Print() is never displayed inside python try/Except

Tags: python, django, try-except

I'm working on a Django app.

Somewhere in my code, I use a try/except like this:

```
for tag in category.get("tags"):
    try:
        newTag, created = MyObject.objects.update_or_create(title=tag.get("title"))
        print("HAHAHA", newTag)
    except:
        pass
```

It works well, newTag is saved, but `print("HAHAHA", newTag)` is never rendered. I don't know why.

Please help

Comment: In your `except`, try using `raise`. I'm betting there's an error in the `update_or_create` function.

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your code in [a complete, minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? My thought process is we're missing something in regards to the object, or something above is causing issues. But yeah, having all the code helps others more knowledgeable in python to assist you. :)

Comment: How about removing the bare try-except that would mask the error?

Comment: Just edited to be a bit more clear. In fact, I run the try except in a for Loop. Sometimes I get an `Integrity constraint error` (I pass then) and sometimes I don't

Comment: You virtually never want to use a bare `except`, and you rarely want to completely ignore an exception. (At the very least, log the exception if for no other reason than to verify that one was raised.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're in a Django app, try

```
import logging
...
logging.debug('HAHA {}'.format(newTag))
```

and watch your server logs.

There lots of additional info on logging in the Django docs, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/logging/

**Adding**

It's also a good idea to log exceptions to flush issues out of hiding.

```
    ...
except Exception as ex:
    logging.warn("Caught {!r}".format(ex))
```

The `logging` module has `exception()` to help with that, but I prefer having more choice on what level an exception is.